# Coin Tosses and Variance 3 Runs of Heads

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

> A group of $n \geq 10$ people sits at a round table. Each person tosses a fair coin. Let $X$ be the number of people whose coin and the coins of both neighbors land heads.
>
> a) Compute $\mathbf{var}(X).$
>
> b) Using the Chebyshev inequality, bound $$ \mathbf{P}(|X-\mathbf{E}(X)| \geq c \sqrt{n}), $$ where $c > 0$ is a constant.

Attempt at a)

Let $X$ be the number of people whose coin and the coins of both neighbors land heads.

Let $X_k = \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{ if the $k^{th}$ toss starts a run of $3$ heads } \\ 0 \quad \text{ otherwise. } \end{cases}$

Then $X=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$.

$\mathbf{P}(X_k=1)=\frac{1}{8} \quad \mathbf{E}(X_k)=1\cdot\frac{1}{8}+0\cdot\frac{7}{8}=\frac{1}{8} \quad \mathbf{E}(X_k^2)=1^2\cdot\frac{1}{8}+0^2\cdot\frac{7}{8}=\frac{1}{8}$

$$\begin{align} \mathbf{var}(X)=&\mathbf{E}(X^2)-\mathbf{E}(X)^2 \\
=&\mathbf{E}(\Sigma_1^n X_i^2)-\mathbf{E}(\Sigma_1^n X_i)^2 \\ =&\Sigma_i^n\mathbf{E}(X_i^2)+2\Sigma_{1\leq i \leq j}^n\mathbf{E}(X_iX_j)-(\Sigma_i^n\mathbf{E}(X_i))^2 \\ =& \frac{n}{8} +2\Sigma_{1\leq i \leq j}^n\mathbf{E}(X_iX_j)-(\frac{n}{8})^2 \end{align} $$

Now $X_iX_j= \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{ if both the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ toss both start runs of $3$ heads}\\ 0 \quad \text{ otherwise. } \end{cases}$

The $\mathbf{P}(X_iX_j=1)=\frac{1}{16}$???

Thus we have that  $$\mathbf{var}(X)=\frac{n}{8}+2\frac{n}{16} -(\frac{n}{8})^2 =\frac{16n-n^2}{64}$$

But this seems wrong as it seems to be negative for higher values of $n$. Which we cannot have negative variance.
thank you for your help.

attempt at b) $$ \begin{align} & \mathbf{P}\left(|X-\mathbf{E}(X)| \geq c \sqrt{n}\right) \\ =& \mathbf{P}\left((X-\mathbf{E}(X))^2 \geq c^2n \right) \end{align}$$

Define $Y=\left(X-\mathbf{E}(X)\right)^2 $ then

$$\begin{align} \mathbf{E}(|Y|)=\mathbf{E}(Y)=\mathbf{E}\left(X-\mathbf{E}(X)\right)^2 = n \end{align} $$

Hency by Chebyshev's Inequality, $$\mathbf{P}(|Y| \geq c^2n) \leq \frac{\mathbf{E}(|Y|)}{c^2n}=\frac{1}{c^2}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following we use $n$ instead of the longer string $10$. (Number of people.)
The indices $j,k$ will be considered modulo $n$. (So $j\pm1$ is also considered after applying $\pm1$ modulo $n$.) The following works for any $n\ge 6$.

Let $X_k$ be the random variable on $\{0,1\}^n$ which is $1$ if the components $k-1,k,k+1$ are all heads, else $0$.

The computation of $\Bbb E X_k = \frac 1{2^3}= \frac 18$ is ok, so 
$$\Bbb E X =\Bbb E\sum_k X_k =\sum_k \Bbb E X_k = \sum_k \frac 18 = \frac n8\ .$$

Now we compute explicitly for some fixed $k$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb E X_k^2 &=\frac 1{2^3}\ ,\text{ positions $k-1,k,k+1$ are head,}\\
\Bbb E X_kX_{k\pm 1} &=\frac 1{2^4}\ ,\text{ positions $k-1,k,k+1$ and also $k\pm2$ are head,}\\
\Bbb E X_kX_{k\pm 2} &=\frac 1{2^5}\ ,\text{ positions $k-1,k,k+1$ and also $k\pm2,k\pm 3$ are head,}\\
\Bbb E X_kX_j &=\frac 1{2^6}\ ,\text{ positions $k-1,k,k+1$ and also $j-1,j,j+1$ are head,}
\end{aligned}
$$
the index $j$ being not among the neighbors of distance $\le 2$ to $k$.
So 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb EX^2
&=
\Bbb E \sum_{k,j}X_kX_j\\
&=
\sum_k\sum_j\Bbb E X_kX_j\\
&=\sum_k\left( 
\frac 1{2^3}
+\frac 1{2^4}+\frac 1{2^4}
+\frac 1{2^5}+\frac 1{2^5}
+(n-5)\frac 1{2^6}
\right)
\\
&=
\sum_k\frac 1{2^6}(8+4+4+2+2+(n-5))
=
\frac {n(n+15)}{64}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the variation of $X$ is
$$
\sigma^2:=
\operatorname{Var}[X]
= E[X^2]-E[X]^2
=
\frac {n(n+15)}{64}
-
\left(\frac n8\right)^2
=
\frac {15n}{64} \ .
$$
So the standard deviation $\sigma$ is the square root of this number, 
a specific constant times $\sqrt n$.

So we apply the inequality of Cebîshev:
$$
\Bbb{P}(\ |X-\Bbb{E}(X)| \geq c \sqrt{n}\ )
=
\Bbb{P}\left(\ |X-\Bbb{E}(X)| \geq c \cdot\frac 8{\sqrt {15}}\sigma\ \right)
\le 
\left(\frac {\sqrt{15}}{8c}\right)^2
=\frac {15}{64c}
\ .
$$

---

For my safe i wanted to verify the above, the following rather simple [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code confirms the results:

```
for n in [6..12]:

    R = [0, 1]
    C = cartesian_product( [ R for _ in range(n) ] )
    p = 1/2^n    # weight of each element in the probability space C

    M1 = 0
    M2 = 0

    for c in C:
        count = len( [ k for k in range(n)
                       if  c[k]       == 1
                       and c[(k-1)%n] == 1
                       and c[(k+1)%n] == 1 ] )
        M1 += p * count
        M2 += p * count^2

    V  = M2 - M1^2

    print "n = %s" % n
    print "\t1. st moment = %s" % M1
    print "\t2. nd moment = %s" % M2
    print "\tVariation    = %s" % V
```

Results:

```
n = 6
        1. st moment = 3/4
        2. nd moment = 63/32
        Variation    = 45/32
n = 7
        1. st moment = 7/8
        2. nd moment = 77/32
        Variation    = 105/64
n = 8
        1. st moment = 1
        2. nd moment = 23/8
        Variation    = 15/8
n = 9
        1. st moment = 9/8
        2. nd moment = 27/8
        Variation    = 135/64
n = 10
        1. st moment = 5/4
        2. nd moment = 125/32
        Variation    = 75/32
n = 11
        1. st moment = 11/8
        2. nd moment = 143/32
        Variation    = 165/64
n = 12
        1. st moment = 3/2
        2. nd moment = 81/16
        Variation    = 45/16
```